# How personalized does a CS postdoc research statement have to be?

Tags: united-states, application, postdocs, job-search, research-statement

I am looking for postdocs in computer science in the US. My spouse and children will not be able to move. So I have decided to look for positions at universities very close to my city. This puts me in the slightly strange position of having to look for postdocs in areas not very connected to my thesis.

(FWIW, my thesis is on a specific area of machine learning (manifold learning), but I am open to positions in ML applications for healthcare, explainable AI, computer vision, natural language processing, collaborative computing, human computer interaction, etc.)

With my location constraints, I am confused about how my research statement can cater to professors in all/most of these areas with minimal rewriting. Or do I have to tailor the statement for every application to reflect the defined current research focus of each lab?

I understand that the part of the research statement that talks about my previous accomplishments will remain the same, but other than that, tailoring the future plans part for each lab seems like a lot of effort. (I have identified around 20 labs so far.)

Comment: just a comment: if you have around 20 labs around you, you have 2020+ opportunities. You live in an scientifically rich region, there are at least 100 companies gravitating around each lab (directly and indirectly). If not in the academia you will surely find a job in one of the 2000+ companies gravitating around the labs. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Look at it from the point of view of a lab director. They will want someone who can be productive right away, because post-doc funding does not provide for an extensive training period. They will want someone that is enthusiastic and has new ideas so that things will get done (papers written, grants submitted, students graduated). You do in fact have to tailor your research statement to each lab and you do have to do some homework trying to figure out what type of person they are looking for. The better a job you do, the more chances to you have of getting a position and of actually fitting in well. A narrative of: "This is my specialization". But "I want to be more of a generalist" / "I want to branch out into this sub-field and this is what I can contribute to it" / "I want to apply my knowledge to a specific area and this is what I can do for you" would be more successful than just asking for a job. Luckily for you, there are many industrial positions that pay quite well, so that there will be less competition for post-docs.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are geographically constrained you actually have the opportunity to go and talk to several people who might be interested about how you might fit into their work. And also, how you might extend their scope to fit with yours, something they might consider.

I suggest you don't pander to their (guessed) needs, but ask them what they actually might get from your skills. Your area is hot at the moment, so you have something to give.

And, your postdoc doesn't necessarily need to be an extension of your "thesis", so think more broadly, which you seem to have done about applications at least.

Note that some teaching might also be important in some places and it might be another bargaining chip if you have those skills.

Longer term, however, work toward figuring out how to make the geographical constraints less binding. This is joint thinking for the whole family, of course.